# É possível criar valores pré-definidos em css?

Tags: css

Como posso adicionar valores pré-definidos em CSS? Como se fosse uma variável para armazenar.

Por exemplo, uma cor (hex ou RGB) para que eu pudesse usar no resto do documento, assim em vez de digitar o valor da cor, digitaria apenas o nome da "variável".

Comment: Você está procurando por [Pré-processadores](http://tableless.com.br/pre-processadores-usar-ou-nao-usar/)

Answer (score 3):

Podes fazer isso criando classes especificas para isso.
Por exemplo, no teu CSS criares uma classe com o nome `preto`, e com o valor `hex` da cor preta:

```
.preto {color:#000;}
```

e no HTML basta chamares a classe da seguinte maneira:

```css
.preto {color:#000;}
.vermelho {color:#ff0000;}
/* e por aí em diante ... */
```

```html
<div class="preto">Olá, eu sou uma classe com o texto com a cor preta</div>
<div class="vermelho">Olá, eu sou uma classe com o texto com a cor vermelha</div>
```

Comment: Chun otima resposta, só adicione o um exemplo possa usar duas classes, pois este é o motivo do atributo `class=""` existir e a sua maior "vantagem". +1

Answer (score 3):

Até o momento não é possível definir valores da mesma forma que estamos acostumados a declarar variáveis, pelo menos não de forma *cross-browser*. Uma forma de simular isto é criar classes que contém as propriedades que seriam aplicadas ao elemento, como mostrado pelo Chun.

Outra alternativa é fazer o uso de [pré processadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101208/4808), mas aí eu estaria fugindo do tema da pergunta que é declarar valores no próprio arquivo css.

Pois bem, há um [projeto na especificação](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/) com o objetivo de tornar possível a declaração de variáveis em folhas de estilos, semelhante à forma que [less](https://github.com/less/less.js) e [sass](https://github.com/sass/sass) trabalham. E a atribuição do valor ficará por conta do atributo **`var()`**, e.g: `background-color: var(--meu-bg)`.

O Firefox e o Chrome já possuem o [recurso implementado](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables), mas lembre-se que ainda é uma tecnologia em experimento. [Nesse artigo da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) há explicações mais objetivas sobre o motivo da implementação e quais problemas ela visa resolver.

---

<sub>**Nota**: No Chrome este recurso precisa ser ativado acessando a aba `chrome://flags`.</sub>

---

Se estiver usando o Firefox, o *snippet* abaixo funcionará e poderá ver o uso das variáveis em ação:

```css
:root {
  --cor-links: red;
  --borda: 2px solid blue;
  --sombra: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

a {
  color: var(--cor-links)
}

div {
  border: var(--borda);
  box-shadow: var(--sombra);
}
```

```html
<a href='#'>Meu Link vermelho</a>

<br><br>

<div>Meu div com borda azul e sombra.</div>
```

Comment: Excelente resposta Renan, só acho que talvez pra complementar seria legal adicionar uma lista com os tipos de pré processador (Ruby, JS, etc). Claro que é apenas uma sugestão e não interfere na qualidade da sua resposta. +1

Answer (score -1):

Sim, mas não diretamente no CSS.

Você deve implementar [{LESS}](http://lesscss.org/) ou [Saas](http://sass-lang.com/) para conseguir.

Essas tecnologias suportam que você crie variáveis e logicas onde estas geram um css a partir de valores pré-definidos.

Comment: Não entenda mal, gostaria de saber em que a sua resposta tem que a do @Renan não tem? Espero que entenda como uma critica construtiva ;)

Comment: Nossa! Absolutamente nada de mais. Gafe minha, que não li a resposta do Renan. Até dei um +1 pra ele. Valeu @GuilhermeNascimento